# Автоматическая выгрузка отчетов из 1с 8.3

Tags: 1с

Есть несколько компаний, лежат в разных информационных базах

Есть доступ только к пользовательской 1с 8.3(не конфигуратор)

Требуется выгружать уже заданные отчеты из интерфейса в Эксель или в xml

Есть ли какая то возможность этот процесс автоматизировать? Выгрузка из каждой информационной базы нескольких отчетов - это очень долго

Читал, что можно писать файлы выгрузок epf, но это очень долго(по описанию на форуме), можно делать через com - объекты с помощью языков программирования

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой то адекватный способ?(запустил скрипт, он прошёлся и сложил в одну папку)?

Потому что собирать все как то по кусочкам из регистров, справочников и документов - тоже не вариант

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Как один из вариантов, посмотрите механизм запуска 1с из командной строки с параметрами. Одним из параметров можно указать внешний отчет/обработку. Встречал варианты, когда запускался  bat файл, в котором был указан перечень баз, и внешний отчет который запускается при открытии.

Пример с одного из сайтов для платформы 8.*: *"C:\Program Files\1cv82\8.2.11.235\bin\1cv8s.exe" ENTERPRISE /F "D:\1C\TestBase" /N user /P* password /Execute "D:\1C\Внешние_обработки_1С\ТестовыйОтчет.epf"

**Преимущества** - в конфигурации отсутствуют какие либо изменения, отчет запускается под пользователем со всеми его правами и ограничениями.

**Недостатки** - необходимо сохранить встроенный отчет как внешний, и немного доделать(заполнение параметров при запуске, механизм сохранения результата).

**com-соединение** - возможно, но присутствует большое количество подводных камней, очень многое зависит от отчета.